# Can i use different versions of cassandra in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, k8ssandra

Can i use different versions of cassandra in a single cluster? My goal is to transfer data from one DC(A) to new DC(B) and decommission DC(A), but DC(A) is on version 3.11.3 and DC(B) is going to be *3.11.7+

* I Want to use K8ssandra deployment with metrics and other stuff. The K8ssandra project cannot deploy older versions of cassandra than 3.11.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K8ssandra itself is purposefully an "opinionated" stack, which is why you can only use certain more recent and not-known to include major issues versions of Cassandra.

But, if you already have the existing cluster, that doesn't mean you can't migrate between them.  Check out this blog for an example of doing that:  https://k8ssandra.io/blog/tutorials/cassandra-database-migration-to-kubernetes-zero-downtime/